# FOR XML *, ELEMENTS is generating empty elements for nulls even though I'm not using XSINIL

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am capturing data from the inserted and deleted tables as xml and saving it to an audit log but for some reason empty elements are begin generated for null values. This appears to contradict the documentation which says:

> The ELEMENTS directive constructs XML in which each column value maps
>   to an element in the XML. If the column value is NULL, **no element is
>   added**. By specifying the optional XSINIL parameter on the ELEMENTS
>   directive, you can request that an element also be created for the
>   NULL value. In this case, an element that has the xsi:nil attribute
>   set to TRUE is returned for each NULL column value.

I'm quite certain I'm not using the XSINIL parameter but the elements are being created all the same. I've tried playing with the generation mode; trying RAW, AUTO, etc but the empty tags remain regardless.

Its a dynamically generated query that looks like:

```
'SET @LogData =
        CASE
            WHEN @EventType = @Insert
            THEN
            (
                SELECT ' + @ColumnList + '
                FROM Inserted
                FOR XML RAW, ELEMENTS
            )
            WHEN @EventType = @Delete
            THEN
            (
                SELECT ' + @ColumnList + '
                FROM Deleted Rows
                FOR XML RAW, ELEMENTS
            )                           
        END;'
```

Where @LogData is of type `xml` and @ColumnList is in the format:

```
[Column1Name],
[Column2Name]
```

Comment: Can you show the query that has this behavior. In some cases you end up with empty tags when you do sub queries in the field list.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce what you see using the code you have posted here. I don't get the empty elements.

Comment: That's odd. I can reproduce the problem every time I run the query. This is, of course, happening in a trigger. I've run similar queries outside of a trigger and they behave as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the table I was testing had nearly every column (400+) set to a default constraint of an empty string, which resulted in those columns being included in the generated xml.

Other tables I tested did not have this default constraint so xml was generated as expected.